# Why is Numpy sometimes returning NaN values when calculating the current loudness?

Tags: python, numpy, audio

For I project of mine, I need to check how loud my surroundings are. I combined two pieces of code to create a pretty accurate decibel meter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyaudio
import numpy as np
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
buffer = []

while True:
    string_audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK) 
    audio_data = np.fromstring(string_audio_data, dtype=np.short)
    loudness = 20*np.log10(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.absolute(audio_data)**2)))
    print(loudness)
```

<sup>Thanks to K K on SO for [the math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943151/) and thanks to YuanGao on [cmsdk.com](https://cmsdk.com/python/how-to-get-sound-pressure-level-db-of-audio-in-python.html) for the recording of sound.</sup>

This returns the loudness in decibels pretty accurately, at least compared to other pretty reliable decibel meters.

However, as soon as the audio starts to get a bit louder, the script often returns either `nan` or numbers that make no sense.

Is there an inherent mistake I'm overlooking or is that just a limitation of this method?

Comment: This seems less a question of algorithm and more a question of debugging. You have to figure out where the NaN first appears and nobody here can answer that for you. Do you see any NaNs in `audio_data`? If not, then break up your equation for `loudness` into its components and determine which function is actually returning NaN. I'd hazard a guess that it is either `np.sqrt` or `np.log10` as you might be passing in values outside of their domain.

Comment: On a very different note.  audio_data will be an array of type np.int16.  When you square it, the resulting array is also going to be np.int16, so you're going to lose bits.  This isn't what's causing your bug, but is another bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @zephyr I did what you told me to do and the first NaN to be seen after `np.mean`-ing the negative results of `np.absolute`-ing and then calculating it to the power of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is of type np.int16.  You're taking the absolute value and then squaring it, but all of this arithmetic is taking place using 16-bit arithmetic.

As an example of the failure, try the following in your interpreter

```
>>> x = np.arange(30000, 30100, dtype=np.short)
>>> print(x * x)
```

and you'll see the problem.  Approximately half the results are negative numbers because they are being truncated to 16 bits.  There is a good chance that your sum is negative, and that the logarithm then gives you `NaN`.

This also explains why it only happens when the music is loud.  Soft music won't overflow.

So change

```
    audio_data = np.fromstring(string_audio_data, dtype=np.short)
```

to

```
    audio_data = np.fromstring(string_audio_data, dtype=np.short).astype(float)
```

and your code will work as intended.

Comment: So in the math, I would have to add change it from `20*np.log10(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.absolute(audio_data)**2)))` to `20*np.log10(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.absolute(np.array(audio_data))**2)))`?

Comment: I think `np.array(audio_data)` keeps the original data type.  You need `audio_data.astype(float)`.

Comment: It now doesn't produce the nan's but it now doesn't go down as much. I don't really have the time now, for now, you are getting an upvote though.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not sure about the algorithm or what you're trying to produce.  I was just trying to figure out where the NaN's were coming from.

Comment: You're approach of converting it to floats worked, however, the instructions from the answer itself are pretty unclear. If you would add more information to your answer, I will definitely accept it.

Comment: Rewrote to make it a more traditional answer.