# How would i find the current decibel level and set it as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, audio, decibel

I'm looking to find the current decibel level in a room using a microphone and setting it as a variable. I haven't been able to find any python code on this so I'm very stuck.

It would be good if the variable could refresh every 0.3 of a second but it doesn't have to.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Have you looked at https://pypi.org/project/soundmeter/? It doesn't provide decibel values but that's complicated as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943151/python-get-volume-decibel-level-real-time-or-from-a-wav-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some python code using the [`pyaudio library`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) that can calculate the dB level using [Root Mean Square (RMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) and print it every 0.3 seconds. Both the `rms` and `db` are available as variables.

```py
import pyaudio
import time
from math import log10
import audioop  

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
WIDTH = 2
RATE = int(p.get_default_input_device_info()['defaultSampleRate'])
DEVICE = p.get_default_input_device_info()['index']
rms = 1
print(p.get_default_input_device_info())

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global rms
    rms = audioop.rms(in_data, WIDTH) / 32767
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue


stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                input_device_index=DEVICE,
                channels=1,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=False,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active(): 
    db = 20 * log10(rms)
    print(f"RMS: {rms} DB: {db}") 
    # refresh every 0.3 seconds 
    time.sleep(0.3)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

### Note

As mentioned in the comment above - measuring dB can be a deeper topic than perhaps you require here. Without some info about the usecase, just note that although the method here is the most common you'll likely see - it only compares peaks to itself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level) has a great discussion about this.

If you need a real world measurement of decibels, you'll need  reference measurements, calibrated equipment and a little more research!

Comment: The above example throws an error:
 db = 20 * log10(rms)
ValueError: math domain error

It is because rms is initialized to 0 and Python does not do logarithmic calculations on less than 1 values. It helps to initialize rms to 1.