# How can I monitoring permanently a speaker device and always it plays i measure the sound decibels peaks using python

Tags: python

I want be able just to get the PC internal sound received from a web site or a player in my speak device I dont want get sound from mic.

I found in the link post below an answer almost solve my problem, but there is a small detail.

[How would i find the current decibel level and set it as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502339/how-would-i-find-the-current-decibel-level-and-set-it-as-a-variable/76813685#76813685)

Modifing the code to adjust my needs the code works just when I put the flag: input=True and output=True also but this generate undesirable reverberation and noises from mic. If i remove the parameter input=True or set to False the input parameter in stream = p.open() method it throws a exception. Is there an alternative to this?

There is many example showing how to read a wave file through to speaker, but does not is what i need.

Would be mandatory in pyaudio audio wire callback between input and output? Always has a input true also?

in the documentation link shows that input flag can be set to false:
https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#class-pyaudio-stream

My operating system is a Windows 11 and the output device is a Realtek.

follows the code, thanks!

```
import pyaudio
import time
import numpy as np
from math import log10
from scipy.io import wavfile

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

WIDTH = 2
RATE = int(p.get_default_output_device_info()['defaultSampleRate'])
DEVICE = p.get_default_output_device_info()['index']
rms = 1

print(p.get_default_output_device_info())

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
global rms
# convert byte data to numpy array
in_data_ = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
# calculate rms
rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(in_data_))) / 32767
return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
output_device_index=DEVICE,
channels=1,
rate=RATE,
input=False,
output=True,
stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active(): 
db = 20 * log10(max(rms, 1e-5))  # to avoid log0 error, use max(rms, 1e-5)
print(f"RMS: {rms} DB: {db}") 
# refresh every 0.3 seconds 
time.sleep(0.3)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: the code in the question is missing the indentation. Please fix this, since indentation matters in Python...